# passing id to javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface

Here is my code. This is the function that is using `this.id` to pass but it's coming up as `undefined` in debugging it.

```
function display()
{
//creates request
request = createRequest();

if(request == null)
    alert("Unable to create request");
else 
{
    //get value of radio button
    var radioChoice = this.id;
    var url = "processing.php?file=" + radioChoice;  // creates URL

    request.onreadystatechange = randomize();   // call back function

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send(null);   // sends request to server
}
}
```

and here is the radio button code:

```
<div class="floatright">
   <p>Select the quiz that has the scambled code you want to fix.</p>
   <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="addpara" onClick="display()">Quiz 1 - addpara()</input><br />
   <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="swaptext" onClick="display()">Quiz 2 - swaptext()</input><br />
   <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="showhint" onClick="display()">Quiz 3 - show_hint()</input><br />
   <br />
</div>
```

Why am I not getting anything to pass into the `radioChoice`?

### Edit

OK, I realized I missed an important part of a prior assignment. This code:

```
 function initPage()
 {
var radioList = document.getElementsByName("quiz").length;
for(var i=0; i < radioList; i++)
{
    document.getElementsByName("quiz")[i].disabled = true;
    document.getElementsByName("quiz")[i].onclick = display;   //register onclick event
}
}
```

The part I had to add was the onclick event registration, but now here is my question: why didn't it work the other way? If I have to have an `onclick` inside the HTML, why wouldn't it find the `id`, but when re-registering it, it does?

Comment: your this.id refers to local variable "var id" inside of display function. You should use event

Comment: @Carine: because the function display() don't know what "this" is. Why don't you call onclick=display('addpara'). Or if you insist on this kind of doing, using jQuery instead.

Comment: What do you expect `this` to resolve to in that function? What does it actually resolve to?

Comment: honestly I'm not sure... I know that i was using a prior assignment and sort of redoing some stuff... and in that one they used this.value and then passed that value into the url string...so instead of creating a value on each radio button, I figured I could use this.id since they already have ids

Comment: @Carine I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with some of the tools available in the console. For example, if you're not sure `this` is what you think it is, simply `console.log(this)` and see what shows up in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as a parameter:

```
function display(element)
```

And use `element` in place of `this` in your code. In your HTML, use:

```
onclick="display(this)"
```

Comment: I think I forgot to re-register the onclick event (its for AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
//for all you onclicks
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id="addpara" onClick="return display(this);">Quiz 1 - addpara()</input>
```

And

```
function display(obj) {
...
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have given

```
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id="addpara" onClick="display()">Quiz 1 - addpara()</input><br />

function display(){
.....

}
```

So here `display` is a member function of window object. So invoking it as `display()` is equal to `window.display();`. Obviously `this` will be window object.

You can pass parameters to `display as shown below

```
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id="addpara" onClick="display(this, event)">Quiz 1 - addpara()</input><br />

function display(element, event){

   // element - input element instance 
   // event  - clcik event object

}
```

but when you give `element.onclick = display;`,  `onclick` which is a member function of the element refers to `display`. So when this event occurs it will be invoked as `element.onclick(event)` which results in element.display(event)`. So inside`display`value of`this` will be the element.

Also see addEventListener : http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php

and

attachEvent : http://help.dottoro.com/ljinxrmt.php